# logstash-filter-translate performance: how many keys would be too much keys in a ruby Hash?

Tags: ruby, logstash

`logstash-filter-translate` its a great filter to perform key/value lookups, but I am concerned about performance at scale and having many keys, let's say 50k keys stored on SSD, for what I understand reading the [source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-translate/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/translate.rb#L197), a ruby `Hash` is pre-populated with the file content (in case of dictionary_path) and the lookup is made first ensuring key exists using a regex `match` and followed by the `get` it in case exists. I suppose this is mostly a Ruby question now but I wanted to ask for experiences.

Comment: did you see this? https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-translate/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/translate.rb#L108-L109

Comment: thank you, yes, it says "A large dictionary could be expensive to match in this case." and what would be great to know is how many keys is considered a large one.